# Does C++ exception framework require kernel support?

Tags: c++, exception, kernel

I am reading about exception support in C++, probably the result applies to other languages as well.

https://wiki.osdev.org/C%2B%2B_Exception_Support

[http://www.ucw.cz/~hubicka/papers/abi/node25.html](http://www.ucw.cz/%7Ehubicka/papers/abi/node25.html)

There is lots of stuff going on, I am a bit overwhelmed. My question is during the unwinding process, does C++ require help from kernel (e.g. <strike>setjmp/longjmp</strike> *as mentioned in comments, these two functions don't involve kernel, however my question remains the same*)? Or the entire process happen only in user space?

I could understand the unwinding of a local thread (think setjmp/longjmp) but is unable to grab how unwinding is done for remote thread.

If all the unwinding magic happens in user space, how can one thread modifies another faulty thread to send it over to handling code without kernel help? Since I believe the thread context information (task struct) lives inside kernel and disallows modification directly from user space, without access to thread context, how is it achieved? Thank you!

---

Update: It looks like I have some fundamental misunderstanding about the task struct. Just bumped into a slide about signal handling ([signal handlers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QVhn.png)) ([http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~donnie/cs124/lectures/CS124Lec15.pdf](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/%7Edonnie/cs124/lectures/CS124Lec15.pdf)), upon entering a signal handler, the kernel stack is empty, all context information lives on user stack. I suppose one can use signal to communicate with other faulty thread to unwind? If that's the case, does it mean C++ exception support requires kernel help since generating signal is a kernel call?

---

Update: As far as the question goes, I am satisfied by Paul's answer. I would like to summarize my understanding on the topic in a broader sense, based on my reading on the comment/answer, please correct me if I am wrong.

C++ exception framework sdoesn't specify particular implementation method, below summary is what I would think it's "common".

There are three sources of exception object, the resulting unwinding is implemented as below:

```
+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                exception source                |                             unwinding method                             |
+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| a) exception created by `throw`                | via code to walk the stack and assembly to transfer control to call site |
| b) exception created by hardware e.g. SIGFPE   | via synchronous signal, and code to walk the stack                       |
|                                                | and assembly to transfer control to call site                            |
| c)* exception created by remote process/thread | via asynchronous signal, and code to walk the stack                      |
|                                                | and assembly to transfer control to call site                            |
+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

*For case c), I am not sure if there is any real-world usage that requires an exception to be created by a foreign process and handled locally, it doesn't fit the `throw`/`catch` semantic either (at least it's doable), I put it here for completeness only.

Comment: *My question is during the unwinding process, does C++ require help from kernel* -- The C++ standard makes no mention of how a compiler implements exception handling, only how exception handling is supposed to behave.

Comment: No. Originally it was implemented as a set of macros, which tells you all you need to know about kernel support. `setjmp()` is sufficient.

Comment: `setjmp` doesn't require kernel help either. It might benefit from it, but that's all.

Comment: @MSalters I have neither stated nor implied that `setjmp()` needs kernel support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

AFAIK this is all implemented in the C++ runtime library (for GCC this would be libgcc_s.so, at least on Linux). This requires code to walk the stack to look for catch blocks and some machine code to jump into such blocks if found. As already mentioned, setjmp/longjmp also do not require the kernel.

Update: don't mix up C++ exceptions and signals. If you'd like to see more of
how C++ exceptions work a good start (if you an comfortable with reading
assembler) would be to use [godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/) to look at the generated assembler for some simple functions that throw and catch exceptions. Beware that
Floating Point Exceptions (FPE) really are signals.

One difference between C++ exceptions and both setjmp/longjmp + signals is
the control flow. The latter two implement 'resumption semantics' with a kind of 'call' (where context gets saved) and 'return' (where the context is restored). C++ exceptions on the other hand implement 'termination semantics ' and have no way of returning to the site of the `throw`.

Signals fall into 2 categories: synchronous signals get delivered immediately (like SIGBUS) and asynchronous ones that get delivered on the next scheduler time slice (like SIGINT). Both cases pass via the kernel. There's no real
difference from a user perspective.

threads do not mix well with anything else that does stack manipulation (setjmp/longjmp and signals). In particular multithreaded applications can
receive asynchronous signals on any thread. To make this easier to manage,
it is common practice to use `pthread_sigmask` to block all signals on
all threads except for one, which will be the signal handling thread.

Comment: Thanks Paul, a follow-up question, suppose I have a a multiple-threaded application, which comprises of a signal handling thread, and other worker threads, from signal handling thread, how can I update the program counter of the faulty worker thread (now interrupted because it has exception) so it will jump to the handling code block next time it's scheduled to run? Or Does my question even make sense?

Comment: You typically have the threads check for a pending exception or stop flag somewhere.

Comment: @Botje could you elaborate more? If the thread is already causing exception, hence interrupts the CPU, how does the thread manage to branch elsewhere to run the code for checking pending exception? Thanks

Comment: Userspace exceptions don't "interrupt the CPU", they are just a regular check+jump to exception handling code. A division by zero is trapped in the kernel and sent back to *the thread that caused it* as a signal. The exception handling code should have installed a handler that redirects to exception handling code. I don't see what use a dedicated signal handling thread would be.